# SQL Union Update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, union

I have this SQL query that selects with limit and order by rand so I get the set number of every `status` then mix the whole result to get a random result not a block for every `status`, and works just as expected:

```
(SELECT * FROM `vicidial_list` WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "AR" LIMIT 1038)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `vicidial_list` WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "CBHOLD" LIMIT 372)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `vicidial_list` WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "NEW" LIMIT 3824)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `vicidial_list` WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "PI" LIMIT 1405)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `vicidial_list` WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "NRP" LIMIT 500)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `vicidial_list` WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "RCAT" LIMIT 500)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Now I want it to update `list_id` to 200 but this doesn't work:

```
(UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "AR" LIMIT 1038)
UNION
(UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "CBHOLD" LIMIT 372)
UNION
(UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "NEW" LIMIT 3824)
UNION
(UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "PI" LIMIT 1405)
UNION
(UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "NRP" LIMIT 500)
UNION
(UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "RCAT" LIMIT 500)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: No UNION with UPDATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run each `UPDATE` as a separate statement:

```
UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "AR" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1038;
UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "CBHOLD" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 372;
UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "NEW" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3824;
UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "PI" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1405;
UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "NRP" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 500;
UPDATE `vicidial_list` SET list_id = 200 WHERE phone_number LIKE "7%" AND list_id NOT IN (500,1000) AND status = "RCAT" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 500;
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about ORDER BY RAND() to shuffle

Comment: You need to add `ORDER BY RAND() ` to each `UPDATE`. I updated my answer with that change.

Comment: Yes I know that but I mean shuffle the whole final result like the output of the first code I posted, not to shuffle every update apart.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Shuffling the results only makes sense for `SELECT`, not for `UPDATE`. Update statements do not return a result set.